# Not able to recognize characters in string - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop, file-io

I'm writing part of a function to help clean the data in a file. I'm effectively cleaning up all the temperatures recorded and converting to Celsius and then to a float. My code for this seems to be ok. However, when I go and try to find a character such as 'C', it will then proceed to say every string has that in it. 
A good example of what happens, is when I run this as is, it returns 0.0 every time because it is recognizing everything as 'NA'. I tried deleting all the code and just trying to find 'C', and the same thing happened.
I have not encountered this issue in any other module where I've done essentially the same thing. Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?

This is what the first few lines of data from my .tsv file look like: 
[image: First few lines_image]

```
for l in y.readlines():
    make_list = l.split()
    if make_list[7] == 'NA' or make_list[7] == 'N/A' or\
       make_list[7] == 'N-A-' or make_list[7] == 'N-A'\
      or make_list[7] == 'NONAPPLICABLE'\
      or make_list[7] == 'NON.APPLICABLE' or 'NON-APPLICABLE':
       make_list[7] = '0'
    if ',' in make_list[7]:
        make_list[7] = make_list[7].replace(',', '.')
    if '-' in make_list[7]:
        make_list[7] = make_list[7].replace('-', '')
    if '°' in make_list[7]:
        make_list[7] = make_list[7].replace('°', '')
    if 'C' not in make_list[7] or 'F' not in make_list[7]\
       or '0' not in make_list[7]:
        if float(make_list[7]) > 45:
            make_list[7] = round((float(make_list[7])-32)*(5/9), 2)
            make_list[7] = str(make_list[7])
    if 'C' in make_list[7]:
        make_list[7] = make_list[7].replace('C', '')
    if 'F' in make_list[7]:
        make_list[7] = make_list[7].replace('F', '')
        make_list[7] = round((float(make_list[7])-32)*(5/9), 2)
    make_list[7] = round(float(make_list[7]), 2) 
    print(make_list[7])
```

Comment: Getting a glimpse of what a few lines of your data look like could help!

Comment: Done! I included the first 10 lines

Comment: Do you have to write out your own function for this, say for an assignment,  or could you use a tool like pandas and pandas.read_csv with tab seperation?

Comment: The problem may actually originate from how you are loading the data. When doing `for l in y.readlines(): make_list = l.split()`, have you tried to display what `make_list[7]` looks like for each line? It seems like the degrees are stored in the 6th column of your .tsv from the image you uploaded.

Comment: @TheHalf-BloodPrince If I display it in a list, it looks perfectly fine. Its just a list of strings. I've done this before in other modules with no problems...

Comment: @EdenTrainor Yes its for an assignment so I can't use pandas unfortunately!

Comment: I think I found the mistake. You're doing `or 'NON-APPLICABLE'` at the end of your first `if` condition, which will always `True` (because `if "string"` does always return `True` if the string is different from `""`) so you end up always changing the value to `0`! You should just change the end of your first `if` condition to `or make_list[7] == 'NON-APPLICABLE'` but you surely knew that.

Comment: @TheHalf-BloodPrince Yes I noticed that and fixed it! So now the issue I have is 'Value Error: Could not convert '40C' to float. The issue here is that 'C' is not being recognized and therefore I can't remove it.... This is where I have my issue

Comment: That quite certainly comes from `if 'C' not in make_list[7] or 'F' not in make_list[7] or '0' not in make_list[7]` where you should be using `and` conditions rather than `or` ones. Doing `if 'C' not in make_list[7] or 'F' not in make_list[7]` will return True because ‘F’ is not in ‘40C’.

Comment: @TheHalf-BloodPrince Bingo! You're a life saver. Everything works now. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Cool! Happy to have helped!